# Visual studio 2013 razor view slow performance

Tags: razor, visual-studio-2013

In my development environment, I have a bit huge razor views(cshtml files).
The file is almost 2000 lines with lots of javascript etc.

My problem is, especially when I copy and paste some lines within file, VS 2013 stops responding for almost 10-15 seconds and come backs alive.

I was wondering about the reason of this behaviour?  And how can I solve this problem cause its really killing my time.

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a bit of a code smell to have such a lot in one view. Consider moving the javascript to a separate file. Without much else to go on, my guess is that the delay is probably VS trying to parse the mix of razor syntax and javascript. Try pausing intellisense and see if that helps.